# HTTP GET inside a api method called by the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, rest, express

Hi I have a rest api set up in Nodejs and the ajax call is working perfectly, that is until I try to call an external REST service from within the method.

Can anyone help me out to work out why this wont work? I'm using Nodejs with Express running on port 3000, basically localhost at the minute. Bellows my work in progress but its been changed alot. I was using the request module but now have went back to http.

```
app.get('/api/exchange', function (req, res){
    var text = '';
    var options = {
        host : 'rate-exchange.appspot.com',
        port : 3000,
        path : '/currency?from=GBP&to=USD',
        method : 'GET'
    };

    var call = http.request(options, function(res) {
        console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
        text = "made it in";

        res.on('data', function(d) {
            text = "here";
        });
    });

    call.end();
    call.on('error', function(e) {
        text = "error";
    });

    res.json({ msg: text });
});
```

Excuse my `classic javascript debuging technique`, I'm basically just using `text` to see where its going.

When I run this I get the following back.

```
{
    "msg": ""
}
```

p.s. anyone knows of any good debuging tools for node I'd be greatful.

Comment: Your app may listen on 3000, but on the server. HTTP traffic can be redirected via iptables, routers or load balancers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `port:3000` is wrong. And you should get response from `http.request` callback function.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res){
    var text = '';
    var options = {
        host : 'rate-exchange.appspot.com',
        //port : 3000,
        path : '/currency?from=GBP&to=USD',
        method : 'GET'
    };

    var call = http.request(options, function(resp) {
        console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
        text = "made it in";

        resp.on('data', function(d) {
            text = "here";
            console.log("response data: "+d);
        });
    });

    call.end();
    call.on('error', function(e) {
        text = "error";
    });

    //res.json({ msg: text });
});
```

Comment: Thank you :) So basically what was happening was I was returning before I got my result as calls are async?

Comment: Yes. That, and the port number.